# How do I format a HTML doc into specific output?

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I am trying to process that HTML document into a specific output, I managed to receive something like this:

```
<div class="country">
  <b>Austria</b>
  <div>Wolfhard</div>
</div>
<div class="country">
  <b>Bulgaria</b>
  <div>Nestor</div>
</div>
<div class="country">
  <b>Croatia</b>
  <div>Sabina</div>
  <div>Florencije</div>
</div>
<div class="country">
  <b>Czech Republic</b>
  <div>Šarlota</div>
  <div>Zoe</div>
</div>
```

I want achieve something like this:

```
Austria 
Wolfhard
Bulgaria
Nestor
Croatia
Sabina, Florencije
Czech Republic
Šarlota, Zoe
```

The maximum amount of names is 3.

Comment: Stack Overflow expects you to show what you've tried, or what your searching has revealed as you try to solve this. This is to avoid situations when people ask for us to write their code for them. So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is an invalid sample. It's important to use the minimum sample data that is valid.

I'm not near my computer but this looks about right:

```
require 'nokogiri'
# encoding: utf8

html = '<html>
  <body>
    <div class="country">
      <b>Austria</b>
      <div>Wolfhard</div>
    </div>
    <div class="country">
      <b>Bulgaria</b>
      <div>Nestor</div>
    </div>
    <div class="country">
      <b>Croatia</b>
      <div>Sabina</div>
      <div>Florencije</div>
    </div>
    <div class="country">
      <b>Czech Republic</b>
      <div>Šarlota</div>
      <div>Zoe</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
```

That sets up a parsed DOM. Because there are UTF-8 characters, it's important to tell Ruby about it if you're using Ruby < v2.0, which is why the encoding line is there:

```
# encoding: utf8
```

Here's how to search the DOM:

```
countries = doc.search('.country')
data = countries.map { |country|
  name = country.at('b').text
  cities = country.search('div').map(&:text)
  {
    :name => name,
    :cities => cities
  }
}
```

That returns an array of hashes, where each hash contains the country name and a sub-array of the city names. From there you can easily iterate over the array and output the values as you need them.

It's all very simple, you just have to think in terms of incremental steps:

1. Because there are multiple `div` tags with `class="country"`, it's possible to iterate over them using `search` or the `css` method. `css` expects a CSS selector, whereas `search` allows either CSS or XPath. I generally use `search` because sometimes I use CSS, sometimes XPath, and might jump between them as I'm developing code because one might flow better. Having to change the method name in addition to the selector is a pain.
2. For each of the selected divs, it's easy to grab the embedded `<b>` tag using `at`, which grabs the first found matching element, then `search` for the matching embedded divs for the cities.